# how to change site url

Tags: url, managed-path

As a part of the 2010 to 2013 site collection restore it kept the original site url which is `http://webapp2013.it/sales` (where sales in sp 2010 exclusive path). But in 2013 it needs to be `http://webapp2013.it/sites/sales`.

I tried following then quickly learn it does not work going from exclusive to wildcard. What are my options?

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://webapp2013.it/sales
$site.Rename("http://webapp2013.it/sites/sales")
```

I even tried set-spsiteurl but that did not work either. Please suggest.

Comment: Could you check if the current webapplication got updated with the path "sales" when you moved it? If so you could just remove it from there.

Comment: Get-SPManagedPath -WebApplication http://webapp2013

Comment: sales explicit path got created under the web app. now i need to move this to sites/sales path where sites is wildcard path

Comment: anything anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

> Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Title, description, and icon under -> Look and Feel

To change the sub-site's URL, changing the site collection URL is not so!

[image: Change Sub-Sites's URL]

**How to Change Site Collection URL in SharePoint?**

To change the site collection's URL, There is no out-of-the-box user interface or direct ways. So, after making sure the destination URL's managed path is already in place and verifying the target site collection URL doesn't exist, I do this three step manual process.

1. Backup the Source Site collection
2. Delete the Source Site collection (Yes, its must! we've to delete the site collection before restoring it. Otherwise you will end up in No content databases are available for this operation GUID conflict issue.)
3. Restore the Backup with the target URL

In MOSS 2007, I used to do it with `STSADM` as to change site collection URL:

`stsadm -o backup -url http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/source -overwrite -filename source.bak`

`stsadm -o deletesite -url http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/source`

`stsadm -o restore -url http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/destination -filename source.bak`

Now, in SharePoint 2010 with the help of PowerShell, Why don't try placing them into a script file to save some time?

[Refer to the following posts, hope it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744494/changing-url-in-sharepoint-2010)

[Change the URL of your site using FrontPage 2002](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SPSite.Rename should work to change the URL of a hostname site collection as long as you have the right managed paths set.

For path-based site collections, you need to use [backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx) and [restore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx) commands to change the URL.

I would do the backup then do a restore to a different (temp) content database. That way you don't have to delete the other site collection first. If you are happy with the restore you can delete the old site and [move the new site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx) back to the other database.